# Access SQLite DB from wix installer custom action

Tags: sqlite, wix, custom-action

I have build Wix 3.7 setup project. To modify SQLite DB during installation I use custom action. But installation throws an error:

```
Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

How can I modify setup project to eliminate this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use a C# custom action to do the work, and include the SQLite.Interop.dll as a reference in your custom action project.  Set the CopyLocal property on the DLL reference to true.  This is all assuming, of course, that SQListe.Interop.dll is managed code.

Comment: I try this, but error remains. I modify my solution. I create small console application a I add it to installation. And custom action calls the exe file and then deletes it.

Comment: Rather than creating a separate console application, what I was referring to was creating an actual C# custom action method and doing the work in there, as described here: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-c-sharp-ca.html

Comment: I use C# custom action, via NuGet I was add System.Data.Sqlite Core (x86/x64), on System.Data.Sqlite reference I set property Copy Local to true. But during installation occures described error.

Comment: Have you tried adding the dll as a Binary element to your WiX XML file, just like the custom action DLL is?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I solve this problem with external configuration application. It is better for me. This solution allows me to solve more problems with post install configuration of my application.

Comment: Hi Martin. I am also getting same error when i am migrating my vdproj to wix installer. Inold application after install event there were some sql lite db creation which i am trying to do via custom action. Can you share how your xml file of wix installer look like after adding binary